# SelectedItem Style don't work for ListBox with DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` with a `DataTemplate` and I need to change the background color of the selected item. I have found some example and tried all of them but probably I missed some point.

I tried to change the `SolidColorBrush` resource and add the trigger for `IsSelected` in the `ListBox` `Style` and for `ListBoxItem` `Style` but none of those work.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxGreenStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ListBoxDragDrop" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="ListBox_Drop"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightGreen" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="lstSlides" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="5" Drop="lstSlides_Drop" DragEnter="lstSlides_DragEnter" AllowDrop="True" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxDragDrop}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionChanged="lstSlides_SelectionChanged" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxGreenStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Height="32" Width="32" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ItemCount}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What is the correct `Style` where to add the triggers or to change the `SolidColorBrush` Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your Style "ListBoxDragDrop" adding the default ItemContainerStyle. Then you can change the SolidColorBrush as you like.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="LightGreen"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="Green"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="LightGreen"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="Green"/>

<Style x:Key="ListBoxDragDrop" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"/>
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
    <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="ListBox_Drop"/>

    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the style I need!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to get rid of the `Style` you declare for your `ListBoxItem` and use instead a `DataTrigger` in the `DataTemplate` you use inside your `ListBox`:

```xml
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

(Don't forget to add `x:Name="grid"` to your `Grid`.)

The `RelativeSource` binding lets WPF look up the visual tree until it finds a `ListBoxItem` (and it will, because you are templating  the `Content` of each `ListBoxItem`).

This will sets the `Background` property of the *content* of the `ListBoxItem` to `Red`. It won't change the `Background` property of the `ListBoxItem` itself!

If that's what you want, the more complicated but most powerful option is to completely overwrite the `Template` property of `ListBoxItem` using a `Style`:

```xml
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This way, you can redefine each property in all states (`Selected`, `Unselected`, `Focused` etc).
This is only a starting point inspired by [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listbox-styles-and-templates).

Sadly, this is not possible to override only part of a `ControlTemplate`. If you rewrite it, you need to rewrite every part of it, even the parts you don't wish to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have tried the first solution you suggested but it change the Grid color instead of the Item Background. It work for what I need but the problem is that the grid is shorter then the Item and the background is green only for the size of the Grid. I don't have any idea how I can set the width to expand the Grid to the size of the Item.

Comment: Yes, that's why i think you have to use the second solution which the WPF way of retemplating a datagrid.

Comment: I tried the second method and it work great for the background but I lose the mouse over effect. I have to add it to the Style? There is a way to keep the default style and change only the item background?

Comment: @user12338473 sadly this is not possible to override only part of a `ControlTemplate`. You indeed need to rewrite or copy-paste from somewhere the MouseOver part of it :/

Comment: Ok, but why trigger for IsSelected don't work? I have used the style that I have posted for a ComboBox and it work correctly to change the color of the selected item without the need to rewrite the Template. Why it don't work for this ListBox?

Comment: Excellent question: it works for `ComboBox` becasue there is a `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` in the default template which lets you change the `Background` property in a simple Style.Trigger. This is not the case for the default `ListBoxItem` template.